# How to change specific ExpandableListView Child Row backgrounds based on property of item stored in row

Tags: android, view, background, adapter, expandablelistview

I have an ExpandableListView that holds certain objects. These objects store a property that determines the background of the view which they are held in. My question is, how do I make sure that these backgrounds are always correct when android recycles views? The issue that I am running into is that when I change this background determining property on a certain row and the xml resource changes on that child row, the next item created for the list uses that same view even though it may not be correct. Here is my code below of my custom ExpandableListViewAdapter that determines the xml resource for the view of the ExpandableListView child row.

```
@Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ToDoItem item = mParent.get(groupPosition).getParentChildren().get(childPosition);
        view = convertView;
            if(view == null) {
                // Check item priority and set background accordingly
                if(item.getPriority() == 2) {
                    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_medium, null);

                } else if(item.getPriority() == 3) {
                    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_high, null);

                } else if(item.getPriority() == 1) {
                    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
                }
            }

        TextView tv = null;
        if (view != null) {
            tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tasktext);
            tv.setText(item.getTask());
        }
        return view;
    }
```

As you can see I am checking if the view is equal to null to make sure my app runs at an acceptable speed. How can I keep my optimization while maintaining the functionality of the backgrounds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The issue that I am running into is that when I change this background determining property on a certain row and the background changes on that row, the next item created for the list uses that same background even though it may not be correct.

Presumably, that is because you have not implemented `getViewTypeCount()` and `getItemViewType()`, to teach the `AdapterView` what object pools to use for caching and recycling purposes. If you will have different row structures based on `position`, you need to properly implement those two methods.

Also, be very careful about modifying list row backgrounds so that you don't interfere with the touch feedback on taps or the selection highlight bar when used with a pointing device (D-pad, trackball, arrow keys, etc.). I would recommend you do just about anything else to distinguish the rows *other* than manipulating the background.

---

Since you apparently are using `ExpandableListView`, not `ListView`, there are up to four different methods that you need to override on your subclass of `BaseExpandableListAdapter`.

Two are `getGroupTypeCount()` and `getChildTypeCount()`. These return the number of distinct row types you are using at the group level and at the child level, respectively. By "distinct row types", I mean "situations where the rows differ enough that your concerns about recycling come into play". Based on the snippet of code in your answer, we can see that you have three distinct child row types, as you are inflating three different layouts based upon priority. Hence, you would have:

```
@Override
public int getChildTypeCount() {
  return(3);
}
```

If you also have different row structures at the group level, you would need to override `getGroupTypeCount()` in a similar fashion.

Then, there are `getGroupType()` and `getChildType()`. These return a value, from `0` to `getGroupTypeCount()-1` and `getChildTypeCount()-1`, indicating which recycling bucket should be used for a given `groupPosition` (or `groupPosition` and `childPosition` for `getChildType()`). If you override `get...TypeCount()`, you **must** also override the corresponding `get...Type()` method.

So, we know we need `getChildType()`. Given your existing code above, that implementation would look like:

```
  @Override
  public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    ToDoItem item = mParent.get(groupPosition).getParentChildren().get(childPosition);

    return(item.getPriority()-1);
  }
```

Since you happen to have `getPriority()` running from `1` to `3`, we can just subtract `1` from that to get a value in our desired `0` to `2` range. If you were basing the row layouts on something else (e.g., third character in the title of the to-do item), you'd need to use that logic in `getChildView()` instead.

And, if you override `getGroupTypeCount()`, you'd also override `getGroupType()`.

Comment: My adapter is extending BaseExpandableListAdapter I don't believe that class has the getViewTypeCount() method. Am I wrong?

Comment: @WizBJacks: "My adapter is extending BaseExpandableListAdapter" -- not if you are using `ListView` as your question indicates. "I don't believe that class has the getViewTypeCount() method" -- there are equivalents, such as `getChildType()` and `getChildTypeCount()`.

Comment: "Also, be very careful about modifying list row backgrounds" -- How would you recommend that I deal with differentiating the rows if not background manipulation?

Comment: @WizBJacks: Icons. Colored side bars. Colored text. Stuff like that. Basically, not full-row backgrounds.

Comment: Would creating separate classes for each cell type be the solution to this problem then?

Comment: Also by background I mean the xml resource I am using to inflate these views. The property of the object stored in the row determines which resource I use but my issue is that the cells are recycled so new objects added to the list will use the last cells resource instead of using the resource based on the property of the item added.

Comment: @WizBJacks: ""the cells are recycled so new objects added to the list will use the last cells resource instead of using the resource based on the property of the item added" -- which is why you have to augment your adapter to teach `AdapterView` about these varying row styles, so the recycling can be done properly, as I indicated in my answer and clarified in my first comment.